# color picker issue in plug in development wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add color picker in wordpress settings API for plugin development. But I am facing problem to do that. I have code this for color picker.

```
// Create this function for color picker.
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'mw_enqueue_color_picker' );
function mw_enqueue_color_picker( $hook_suffix ) {
// first check that $hook_suffix is appropriate for your admin page
wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script-handle', plugins_url('my-script.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'wp-color-picker' ), false, true );
```

}

```
//Call it in my input field option
<tr valign="top">
<th scope="row"><label for="cursor_color">ScrollBar Color</label></th>
<td>
<input id= "cursor_color" type="text" name="ppmscrollbar_options[cursor_color]" value="<?php echo stripslashes($settings['cursor_color']);?>" class="my-color-field"/><p class="description">Select Icon holder color here. You can also add html HEX code.</p>
</td>
</tr>
```

//In my-script.js file I have written this bellow code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.my-color-field').wpColorPicker();
});
```

I did not solve the issue. Can anyone tell me what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure why your code is not working, maybe the issue is not in the code you posted... The following is almost the same as yours, but a complete demonstration:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'color_pick_so_23696173');

function color_pick_so_23696173()
{
     $my_page = add_dashboard_page( 
        'colorpick', 
        'colorpick', 
        'add_users',
        'colorpick-page', 
        'color_pick_callback_so_23696173' 
    );
    add_action( "admin_print_scripts-$my_page", 'enqueue_so_23696173' );
}
function enqueue_so_23696173() 
{
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 
        'colorpick', 
        plugins_url( 'my-script.js', __FILE__ ), 
        array( 'wp-color-picker'),
        false,
        true
    );
}
function color_pick_callback_so_23696173()
{ 
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <table>
            <tr valign="top">
            <th scope="row"><label for="cursor_color">ScrollBar Color</label></th>
            <td>
            <input id= "cursor_color" type="text" name="ppmscrollbar_options[cursor_color]" value="" class="my-color-field"/>
            <p class="description">Select Icon holder color here. You can also add html HEX code.</p>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

And **`my-script.js`** is exactly the same as yours.

Comment: Thank you for replying me. My problem is solved now.

Comment: But did you find the origin of the problem?

Comment: Yes. I have find it.conflict with jQuery. When I use jQuery from wordpress then problem solved.